# Solar cell efficiency on self tabbed cells

Tags: solar-cell

I am tabbing solar cells myself and of course it is not done perfectly on all tabbing wires.

My question is, does solar cell efficiency drop if tabbing wire is not fully tabbed on all places, or do electrons flow to the closest soldered part if there are empty spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Supplying a photo of your cells and your soldering would be a very good idea To be certain that what you are describing is properly understood, but ...

The following is based on my experience in this area:

A partial attachment of the tabbing wire to the solar cell should work properly. If you make as good a solder joint as you can, and have a good joint along say at least 10% of the connection area, then the majority of resistance to current flow will occur within the cell.

You can test this by soldering tabs to some cells with as much contact area as possible, and soldering some other tabs with very little contact area.  Expose all cells to sunlight and measure & record current flow when the cell is short-circuited with an ammeter. There will be some variation between cells, but if the soldering is OK you will not be able to tell which way the cells are soldered by looking at the short circuit currents.

Comment: Good message here: Test it out!

Answer (score 1):

The current would flow with even a small connection, but there are chances of the soldering not been strong enough (as it is not in contact with the entire surface of the cell) and the tabs might peel off causing the bus-bars to get damaged. As the cells are connected in series even if one of the cell gets disconnected the entire connection fails. So as a practice it is better to have proper soldering techniques

As far as the industry is concerned the cells are laminated with Ethyl Vinyl Acetate (EVA) sheet. If the solder is not proper there are chances of air to penetrate will laminating and will reduce the life of the panel. (They have to survive for 25 long years).

Answer (score 0):

By my experience with using salvage cells is even a hair line crack can effect the output. It may read ok on the multimeter but handling and heat can cause it to shift out put goes to shots to crap. Flex each one just a little an make sure its not cracked at all or weak then test it.